# Preventing lines from overlapping

Tags: algorithm, line, path-finding

Imagine a GPS navigation system with lines connecting different locations. These lines are on roads (always straight, never curved) passing through multiple points. A simple representation is shown below.

[image: Simple]

Now it is possible that lines overlap. Lines that overlap must be placed in complete adjacent to the existing lines. How can I achieve this effect?

How can I build a system lines stay adjacent to overlapping lines and never cross over each other?

Intended-

[image]

Not intended-

[image: Not intended]

Comment: What you ask might not always be possible.

Comment: What about a best solution or a workaround to show overlapping lines?

Comment: This may be too simple, but in some cases you might use one of the two: adjust the opacity to have semi-transparent lines (e.g., alpha=.5), or use lines with different widths. If you have different widths, draw the wider one before. Both will in many case result a visually clear illustration. (And both are bad if you have more than two or three overlapping lines.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the red line does not intersect itself, define a 'left' of the line, in relation to its direction, you can use a normal to the line and pick a side. Then add a factor of this normal to each end point of your original line, and you have the blue line end points.

Comment: This may be what you meant, but with a few more words. There will be a fair bit of calculating intersections, as the route may even make a full circle, so just adding the same vector to each intersection is not enough. But the basic idea is there, offset each segment to the "left" (segments must have a direction) with a certain amount. Then calculate the intersection for each pair of consecutive lines. The intersection offset can be directly calculated by using the directions of the intersecting segments, a bit of vector arithmetics is needed.